# Polynomials vs CNF forms and P=BPP

Tags: complexity-theory, 3-sat

Given a $3\mathsf{SAT}$ form to decide satisfiability takes exponential time.

Any boolean function has an unique polynomial representation. So decide $3\mathsf{SAT}$ satisfiability reduces to whether a given polynomial is identically $0$. However deciding $\mathsf{PIT}$ is believed to be in $\mathsf{P}$ since we think $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{BPP}$.

However any $3\mathsf{SAT}$ instance can be thought as a boolean function. So does it mean we believe $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ as well? Of course not. However I am unable to figure what mistake I make in my reasoning.

Could someone explain?

I think this has to do with boolean and arithmetic circuit difference. However I am unsure how to correct my misunderstanding.

Comment: So deciding 3SAT reduces to PIT - proof?

Comment: @Eugene I am saying I make a mistake. I am trying to understand.

Comment: I am not fully understood, but if you say for a 3-sat you compute the polynomials just as is, like saying let this Boolean variables be continuous. Then boolean formula can be unsatisfiable, i.e. for every $x_i =0$ or $x_i=1$ polynomial is 0(1) but it is not necessary 0 for another point

Comment: @Eugene Given a CNF form can we consider it as a boolean function?

Comment: no doubt CNF is a boolean function. Actually recall that a boolean function is a mapping from $\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ and the well known result is that it can be represented as CNF.

Comment: @Eugene Given a boolean function can we consider the unique real polynomial over $\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ that represents it?

Comment: yes, but it does not reduce to PIT. Let's say you have this polynomial and you formula is unsatisfiably. Then for every point on 0-1 grid you have value 0. However, the polynomial itself might be not zero. For a single variable see $x(x-1)=0$. The Boolean function is unsatisfiable, but the polynomial is not zero everywhere

Comment: @Eugene is that the only point I miss?

Comment: looks like. If you restrict a polynomial over a finite field and ask if it equals zero everywhere there, this problem is NP-Complete (I'm not completely sure about this). PIT is thought to be easy only because variables are real so you really check after opening all brackets and doing the math you have 0 or not.

Comment: @Eugene 'If you restrict a polynomial over a finite field and ask if it equals zero everywhere there, this problem is NP-Complete' is it so? what is the short certificate for yes instance? may be co-NP-complete?

Comment: coNP, you are right.

Comment: @Eugene Could you not expand $x(1-x)$ to get $x^2-x$ and then use the fact that $x^2=x$ since $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$ to say that $x(1-x)$ simplifies to $x-x$and thus $0$